# Convert currency values

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, currency, cultureinfo

I am trying to convert one currency to another

eg.

```
  decimal value= 0;
  var text = "£135";
  decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("fa-IR"), out value);
```

this result *value* as "0". Am I doing anything wrong here?

Or is there any other way of doing this?

Any help is appreciate!!!

**Update**

I tired

```
var value= string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:c}", text);
then value = "£135"

var value = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US", false), "{0:c}", text);
then value = "£135" 

var value = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US", false), "{0:c}", "135");
then value = "135"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to convert decimal or string to currency in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093423/best-way-to-convert-decimal-or-string-to-currency-in-c)

Comment: @JustinPihony: As is says  I tried `var value= string.Format(new CultureInfo("fa-IR"), "{0:c}", text);` which gives same value which is **£135**.. Any idea?

Comment: The Arabic lettering is 'rial' (Iran's currency).  Looks like it's working for the culture, just not the number.

Comment: @mcalex: I made a mistake by passing wrong value. I have update the question. it still return the same value

Comment: Please note that the data type has to be numeric (decimal, int) and not string. As a result, pass `135` instead of `"135"`

Comment: what happens if you don't initialize value?  just use `decimal value;` in the first line

Comment: Have you tested whether TryParse returns true or false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably do something more like this if you want the currency symbol

```
var s = 135.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

This will give you your $135.00

You can only work off of non-string values, though. So, if you want to convert them back and forth, then you will need to go from a string back to a decimal first

```
  var s = 135.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
  //$135.00
  decimal x;
  var tryParse = decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out x);
  var s1 = x.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
  //ريال 135/00
```

Comment: This works fine. But in my case I have a `dropdown` where we can select different currency. When selected value changes it get the currency eg. `En-US` from dropdown, and try to convert current value which is in a text box and update it with new currency.  This work only in the first time. Any idea why?

Comment: You would have to post the code...probably should be a separate question, though. Link me to it and I can take a look

Answer (score 1):

`"£135"` this `Contains Currency Symbol` and `decimal.TryParse` not able to get the Symbol.. so only it returns `"0"` ...

Try to Pass the Value with out Symbol then it works.... other wise use `string.Format` in code...

```
decimal value= 0;
var text = "135";
decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("fa-IR"), out value);
```

Comment: something like `var value = string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US", false), "{0:c}", "135")` ??

Comment: `NumberStyles.Any` should have taken care of that in the first attempt

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: YES, Otherwise give the value of var text = "135"; will get works...

Comment: @Pandian: It will return `135` where I am expecting `$135`. It missing the currency-symbol

Comment: @Pandian: Remove the quotes surrounding 135. i.e. `var text = 135`

Comment: @Pandian: looking at your updated answer passing `NumberStyles.Any` mean it will contain `AllowCurrencySymbol` so you can pass the "£135" is it?